# Using PHP 7.0 on an apache server

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, raspbian

I have an Apache 2.4 server running on raspbian (raspberry pi) and I am trying to use php. I have php 7.0 installed on the pi, however I was wondering how to use php in my web pages. I have tried to install mod_php (not even sure if this is what I need) but to no success. What should I do?

Comment: You have to give more information than this for us to be able to help you.
There are plenty of tutorials out there to get php and apache configured

Comment: I have ran `sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mcrypt php-mysql`                                                                                                                   and it installs correctly, I have also configured apache to run index.php first, however no php code ever runs when I open it in a web page

Comment: First of all, I dont see that you are installing apache. Next to that, you need extra repositories to install php7. Just google "Raspbian php7"

Comment: @Mazzy PHP 7.0 is available from the current repositories of Raspbian Stretch.

Comment: @jamesclarke How exactly do you open php code "in a web page"?